# module can't find package com.google.gson.stream

Tags: kotlin, gradle

a project i'm working with has a dependency on kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics. so i added kotlin-gradle-plugin-1.5.0.jar. now i'm getting an error that it can't find gson.streams. any idea what this is all about?

```
Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.module.FindException: Error reading module: E:\jars\kotlin-gradle-plugin-1.5.0.jar
Caused by: java.lang.module.InvalidModuleDescriptorException: Package com.google.gson.stream not found in module
```

i already have gson-2.8,6.jar in my classpath.

Answer (score 0):

The Jar `kotlin-gradle-plugin` version 1.5.0 seems to have runtime dependency with `com.google.code.gson » gson`

you can see that in the `Runtime Dependencies` section from [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-gradle-plugin/1.5.0)

In order to rectify this, you have to add it as a plugin

like below

```
plugins {
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.<...>' version '1.5.0'
}
```

This is the recommended way from [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/gradle.html#plugin-and-versions)

Comment: Does not work. When trying `org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm`, I get `Invalid module name: 'native' is not a Java identifier`